# 35% Maximum Frequency in the Windows Resource Monitor

Tags: windows-8, laptop, cpu, power-supply, battery

I have a problem with my CPU as it runs over 100% on battery yet it doesn't go beyond 35% when plugged in.

Yes, I've checked power management options like a million times for high performance and maximum processor state = 100%. And yes, I've checked my hard drive for malware, defragmented and cleaned it.

I tried using CoreTemp, it showed that the temperature is OK but the power supply is weird, 5~9 Watt when plugged in and about 22 Watt on battery.

```
Specs:
  DELL Inspiron N7110
  Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2670QM CPU @ 2.20GHz
  Maximum speed:    2.20 GHz
  Sockets:  1
  Cores:    4
  Logical processors:   8
  Virtualization:   Disabled
  Hyper-V support:  Yes
  L1 cache: 256 KB
  L2 cache: 1.0 MB
  L3 cache: 6.0 MB
  Speed:    0.77 GHz
```

Does anyone have any ideas why my processor maxes out at 35% while plugged in?

**EDIT :** Strangely, I removed the optical drive (or as some prefer to call it *CD-Player*) and now it only *sometimes* go down to 35% with a maximum of 120%. I still want to know why. And if possible how to limit the maximum to 100%.

Comment: Check if you have any power management software provided by manufacturer. It may be the culprit.

Comment: I've personally installed everything from the OS to drivers to utilities. And I put no such thing.

Comment: Ok, so was it working before? How long ago has it stopped to work?

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "35%" and "100%".  Percent of what?  How are you measuring this?

Comment: I don't measure anything... I got my percentage from Windows Resource Monitor as stated in the title.

Comment: @WajihAziza: If possible, try a different power supply, making sure that it is compatible.

Comment: @James : I see, it worked. It seems my charger isn't working well. I guess the only possible thing I can do is to buy a new one. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First, check to see if your laptop is overheated.

Second, check your BIOS to ensure that CPU SpeedStep is enabled.

Third, try to remove and re-plug your power adapter and/or battery.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Been there, done that. I found no way to limit the processor's maximum speed, short of changing the power plan to "power saver".